# Set of One-Variable Computable Function and one Local Contest Questions?

Tags: logic, computability

I prepare for local complexity contest and review some old question banks. I get stuck in one problem and no idea how we can solve it. please share your idea or help with this question:

> Suppose $C$ is a set of all one-variable computable functions,
>   $C^{(n)}$ is a set of  all one-variable computable functions using
>   program with at most $n$ instruction, $C_{(n)}$ is a set of all
>   one-variable computable functions using program with just allowed to use
>   variables $X, Y, Z_1, ..., Z_n$.

Which one is Correct:

> a) $ \exists n C^{(n)} = C , \exists n C_{(n)} = C$
>
> b) $ \exists n C^{(n)} = C , \forall n C_{(n)} \subsetneq C$
>
> c) $ \forall n C^{(n)} \subsetneq C , \forall n C_{(n)} \subsetneq C$
>
> d) $ \forall n C^{(n)} \subsetneq C , \exists n C_{(n)} = C$

Answer sheet (2). Any Expert can describe and help idea for solving this difficult contest question?

Edit 1: 
I think the answer sheet is wrong (b is not correct). There are infinitely many one-variable computable functions, yet depending on our definition of "program", there could only be finitely many programs of length at most $n$. Indeed, "instructions" usually come from a finite set. On the other hand, one could envision a definition of program which includes such statements as $x \gets N$ for an arbitrary $N$ (which count as a single instruction!). If such statements are allowed, the argument in the following paragraph shows that we can in fact do with a finite number of instructions.

On the other hand, for every reasonable definition of program, only finitely many variables should suffice. Indeed, a universal program uses only finitely many variables. So the correct answer is (a) or (d), depending on our definition of "program".

Who can say, why the final answer sheet choose another option? am I wrong?

Comment: @CarlMummert, I ran into this question. without any knowledge about it. why you put it on-hold? it's unfair.

Comment: @Xoff would you please share your idea here?

Comment: @CarlMummert, I say about try, please correct me.

Answer (score 1):

I would answer (d) because, whatever is the definition of instruction, it usually means something bounded, hence $C^{(n)}$ is finite and can't be equal to $C$.

However, you only need two integer variables with usual arithmetic operators to simulate any turing machine. So $C=C_{(0)}$. Could be a little bit more depending of your programming system.

Comment: Would you please add a bit more detail ? I means (a) or (d) is true, but (d) is better?

Comment: @LoveComplexity All answers are obviously disjoint : only one can true.

Comment: @LoveComplexity As I say to my students, if you don't understand something, you should ask a question about what you don't understand. If you only say "I don't understand", it doesn't help me to know what I can say, and I suspect you didn't do any effort to understand what I explained. So what precisely is your question about my explanation ? :)

Comment: okey, I means 1) The instruction set are finite; there are finitely many instructions so (d) is correct. 2) There is an instruction $X_2 \gets m$ for arbitrary $m$ (or more generally, we can implement this operation using a bounded number of instructions), and (1) is correct.  am I wrong?

Comment: @LoveComplexity you're right ! But usually we count $X\leftarrow m$ as $n+1$ instructions where $n$ is the number of operations needed to define $m$, that's why I prefer answer $(d)$ to $(a)$. But I think you understand well the question.

Comment: In (2) case, given  universal program with $n$ instructions, we can simulate any program using only $n+1$ instructions, by prepending the instruction $X_2 \gets m$ for the correct value of $m$. So (a) is correct. why you prefer (d), this is my misunderstanding point.

Comment: @LoveComplexity because usually, an instruction is a basic operator, and it's bounded and atomic, it's not a whole expression with unbounded length. Even if you can write a universal program with $n$ instructions doesn't mean you obtain all computable functions : simulation is not the same as having all functions directly ! (In a very dramatic case, you could take a singleton set containing only a universal function, this set is of course not the same as the set of all computable functions)

Comment: so my last question is, (a) is not false, but it's better to choose (d) ? or no, (a) is false?

Comment: @LoveComplexity With usual definitions, $(a)$ is false and $(d)$ is right. However with no proper definitions of all the terms of the question, it may be debatable.

Comment: thanks so much professor, I LOVE YOU That so kind with students.

Answer (score 0):

The explanation in the question seems to be correct - the answer could be (a) or (d) depending on how "instruction" is defined.

Comment: Thanks, but would you please say different among (a) and (d)? I'm not sure. thanks.

Comment: You have already said everything there is to say.

Comment: But Exactly, I not very well understood, maybe with clear definition I Got it. if I didnt waste your time, please shortly describe it. thanks from your valuable time.

Comment: I would be so glad if you share your idea about other answer. thanks.